# Install nginx::source chef recipe without starting nginx right after installation

Tags: nginx, chef-infra

I need to install [nginx::source](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nginx) chef recipe without starting nginx right after installation. How can I do it? Can I somehow do this with wrapper cookbook or something?

Thanks an advance.

Comment: which template did you run ? ubuntu or default

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan default

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I got you, mate. It's in `nginx-2.7.6/templates/default/sv-nginx-run.erb`, right?

Comment: I need to rewrite it without line `exec <%= node['nginx']['src_binary'] %> -c <%= node['nginx']['dir'] %>/nginx.conf` ?

Comment: you did run cookbook `nginx_service_test` right ?

Comment: nope, it's all about [this cookbook](https://github.com/miketheman/nginx)

Comment: How did you add recipe to run_list ?

Comment: include_recipe "nginx::source"

Answer (score 1):

You need [rewind](https://github.com/thommay/chef-rewind) to modify the service resource from nginx cookbook.

Something like this (untested, replacing action start by enable):

```
rewind 'service[nginx]' do
  action :enable
end
```

In a pure chef manner without the rewind cookbook (from Seth Vargo's blog [here](https://sethvargo.com/changing-chef-resources-at-runtime/)):

```
r = resources(service: 'nginx')
r.action :enable
```